# Rails 4 assets - two different digests getting generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I clearly must be Doing Something Wrong here. I'm wrestling with the asset pipeline (again).  I have a custom font, and it seems to me to get everything to compile properly I need to use `asset_path()` in multiple places, but it's having an unexpected effect.

I realize there are several ways to do this, but here's what I have currently:

In `application.css.scss.erb`:

`@import "<%= asset_path("my-font.css") %>";`

`my-font.css`'s source file is `app/assets/stylesheets/my-font.css.erb` (it needs to be an `.erb` because I am also using `asset_path()` there as well).

In `application.rb` I am adding `my-font.css` to the precompile list.

    `config.assets.precompile << 'my-font.css'`

When I clean out `public/assets` and run `rake assets:precompile` Everything's getting compiled, with digests, but the digest applied to the actual file is not the same as the digest calculated and put in to `application.css`.

The resulting file is
`public/assets/my-font-2f25682a1ea904a866ef9f44101a5a2e.css` but in `public/assets/application-bba2edaee36771f4bdb5c89b8ec90aaf.css` the reference to it is:

`@import url(/assets/my-font-ed843d3b174ca427edf963e473ad9e9b.css);`

I realize I'm probably using `asset_path()` more than I should, and also importing files via url() instead of requiring them, but this has gotten me the closest to having things working.

I suspect one of the digests is being calculated on my-font.css *before* it goes through ERB, and the other after, but I don't understand why nor how to fix it.

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you use the `depend_on_asset` directive?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19688338/1066093

Answer (score 6):

I would guess that you're cleaning your assets just by emptying `public/assets`. That's not enough, you'll also need to empty your `tmp/cache/assets`, or just run `rake assets:clobber` to do both.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolve this kind of dependency by injecting the raw contents of the asset you want to bundle into a composite asset like `application.scss.erb`.  You need to explicitly declare the dependency (so that changes in `my-fonts.css` cause a regenerations of `application.css`) and then inject the contents:

`application.scss.erb`:

```
// Should be at Top of File
//= depend_on_asset my-fonts.css

//... wherever in the file you want the contents injected:
<%= environment['my-fonts.css'] %>
```

How does this work?  During asset pipeline compilation, the environment here has a hash of all pre-compiled asset contents.  This allows you to inject the compiled contents from `my-fonts.css` into your composite asset.  Because we're manually injecting the value, we need to explicitly create a dependency to track this relationship via `depend_on_asset`.

One thing to keep in mind is that multiple asset pre-processors (SCSS, ERB, etc) are processed from the "outside in", so the contents of the `my-fonts.css` asset will be compiled/injected during the ERB processing as CSS output.  They will be included within the asset before SCSS processing.  This shouldn't pose a problem, because if this is an SCSS asset, any SCSS references will be compiled before injection into the parent asset.